# How to call one function(method) from another in a class?

Tags: python, function

I want to create switch case, but don't know how to call one function from another. For example, in this code I want to call `OrderModule()` when I press "O".

Actually I've already done whole program in Java, maybe somebody know, how to convert it more easily without re-writing it all?

```
class CMS:

    def MainMenu():
        print("|----Welcome to Catering Management System----|")

        print("|[O]Order")
        print("|[R]Report")
        print("|[P]Payment")
        print("|[E]Exit")
        print("|")
        print("|----Select module---- \n")
        moduleSelect = raw_input()
        if moduleSelect == "o" or moduleSelect == "O":
            ---
        if moduleSelect == "r" or moduleSelect == "R":
            ---
        if moduleSelect == "P" or moduleSelect == "P":
            ---
        if moduleSelect == "e" or moduleSelect == "E":
            ---
        else:
            print("Error")
    MainMenu()
    def OrderModule():
        print("|[F]Place orders for food")
        print("|[S]Place orders for other services")
        print("|[M]Return to Main Menu")
    OrderModule()
```

Comment: Are you asking how to call a function?

Comment: Yes, like method in java

Comment: 'self' is the keyword in Python, and it should be explicitly passed as a first method's argument. Also, this code could be rewritten using Strategy design pattern.

Comment: I read about 'self', but when apply it, get message *name 'self' is not defined*

Comment: @KidBinary `self` is not a keyword, it's just a convention that first argument to instance method is `self` (and first argument to `classmethod` is `cls`).

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Sure thing, that's what I said - "explicitly passed as a first method's argument". By "keyword" I meant **the answer**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the deal. I'll refactor the code a bit for the sake of your understanding of Python and maybe some good tip about design patterns.

Please, consider this example over-simplified and somewhat excessive, it's done with singular purpose to boost your emerging development skills.

First, it's good to familiarize yourself with [Strategy Design Pattern](http://www.laurencegellert.com/2011/08/python-strategy-pattern/), which comes in handy for such tasks (in my personal opinion). After that you can create a base module class and it's strategies. **Notice how `self` (variable that represents the instance of the object itself) explicitly passed as a first argument to classes methods**:

```
class SystemModule():
    strategy = None

    def __init__(self, strategy=None):
        '''
        Strategies of this base class should not be created
        as stand-alone instances (don't do it in real-world!).
        Instantiate base class with strategy of your choosing
        '''
        if type(self) is not SystemModule:
            raise Exception("Strategy cannot be instantiated by itself!")
        if strategy:
            self.strategy = strategy()

    def show_menu(self):
        '''
        Except, if method is called without applied strategy
        '''
        if self.strategy:
            self.strategy.show_menu()
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError('No strategy applied!')


class OrderModule(SystemModule):
    def show_menu(self):
        '''
        Strings joined by new line are more elegant
        than multiple `print` statements
        '''
        print('\n'.join([
            "|[F]Place orders for food",
            "|[S]Place orders for other services",
            "|[M]Return to Main Menu",
        ]))


class ReportModule(SystemModule):
    def show_menu(self):
        print('---')


class PaymentModule(SystemModule):
    def show_menu(self):
        print('---')
```

**Here `OrderModule`, `ReportModule` and `PaymentModule` can be defined as first-class functions, but classes are more obvious for this example.** Next, create a main class of your application:

```
class CMS():
    '''
    Options presented as dictionary items to avoid ugly
    multiple `if-elif` construction
    '''
    MAIN_MENU_OPTIONS = {
        'o': OrderModule, 'r': ReportModule, 'p': PaymentModule,
    }

    def main_menu(self):
        print('\n'.join([
            "|----Welcome to Catering Management System----|", "|",
            "|[O]Order", "|[R]Report", "|[P]Payment", "|[E]Exit",
            "|", "|----Select module----",
        ]))

        # `raw_input` renamed to `input` in Python 3,
        # so use `raw_input()` for second version. Also,
        # `lower()` is used to eliminate case-sensitive
        # checks you had.
        module_select = input().lower()

        # If user selected exit, be sure to close app
        # straight away, without further unnecessary processing 
        if module_select == 'e':
            print('Goodbye!')
            import sys
            sys.exit(0)

        # Perform dictionary lookup for entered key, and set that
        # key's value as desired strategy for `SystemModule` class
        if module_select in self.MAIN_MENU_OPTIONS:
            strategy = SystemModule(
                strategy=self.MAIN_MENU_OPTIONS[module_select])

            # Base class calls appropriate method of strategy class
            return strategy.show_menu()
        else:
            print('Please, select a correct module')
```

For this whole thing to work, there's a simple starter at the end of file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cms = CMS()
    cms.main_menu()
```

Here you go. I really hope that this snippet will help you to dive deeper into Python : )
Cheers!